# How to make arbitrary output section loadable by GDB?

Tags: gdb, embedded, ld

I'm trying to debug a program on LH75401 device with ARM7TDMI core using GDB. When I invoke "load" command, GDB loads only ".text" output section. How do I make it so that it loads not only the ".text" section but some other sections too? I tried to use PHDRS command in the linker script to make some sections loadable but it did not help. Here is my linker script:

```
USR_STACK_SIZE = 0x100;
IRQ_STACK_SIZE = 0x100;


MEMORY
{
   EXTROM(wx) : ORIGIN = 0x44000000, LENGTH = 0x100000
   EXTRAM(wx) : ORIGIN = 0x48000000, LENGTH = 0x100000
   INTRAM(wx) : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0x4000
   TCMRAM(wx) : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 0x4000
}


PHDRS
{
    EXTROM PT_LOAD;
    EXTRAM PT_LOAD;
    INTRAM PT_LOAD;
    TCMRAM PT_LOAD;
}


ENTRY(rst_handler)


SECTIONS
{
    .vect :
    {
        *(.vect)
    }
    > TCMRAM AT
    > TCMRAM
    : TCMRAM


    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
    }
    > EXTROM AT
    > EXTROM
    : EXTROM


    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }
    > EXTRAM AT
    > EXTRAM
    : EXTRAM


    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }
    > EXTRAM AT
    > EXTRAM
    : EXTRAM


    .usr_stack :
    {
        . += USR_STACK_SIZE;
        .  = ALIGN(8);
    }
    > EXTRAM AT
    > EXTRAM
    : EXTRAM


    .irq_stack :
    {
        . += IRQ_STACK_SIZE;
        .  = ALIGN(8);
    }
    > EXTRAM AT
    > EXTRAM
    : EXTRAM
}
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `readelf -WlS` for the binary you're trying to load.

Comment: @Andrew Fortunately I solved this problem. In my case it was necessary to add a special attribute for the section in the source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I solved this problem. It was necessary to add a special section attribute in the source file. The attribute is "a", meaning that the section is allocatable. That's all.